# Spawning Animated Deformable Objects in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I need to simulate cloth models in Gazebo while using the PR2 model. I have already created cloth meshes by using Blender 2.64 and exported them as COLLADA .dae files. I tried to spawn them as .urdf models as it is explained in [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/SpawningObjectInSimulation) but unfortunately it didn't work. Curiously, the models are imported correctly (they appear in the left panel of Gazebo) but I can't see them in the 3D environment. I tried changing the scaling but that didn't work either.

Furthermore, I was looking at [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.0/intermediate/animate_pose), but it tells Gazebo to not simulate the model in the physics engine and I must have this capability activated. In other words, my goal is to simulate the PR2 robot graphing the cloth from one corner, and the cloth would drape and wrinkle appropriately due to the gravitational field. Would I be able to accomplish this using Gazebo? and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks,

Stalin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/305/spawning-animated-deformable-objects-in-gazebo/) by [Stalin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/104/stalin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Deformable physics is not currently offered by Gazebo because its underling physics engine, ODE, does not. I know they plan on integrating the Bullet physics engine which does do deformable physics, but it's not going to be soon as the gazebo team is currently focused on supporting necessary changes for the [DRC](http://www.darpa.mil/Our_Work/TTO/Programs/DARPA_Robotics_Challenge.aspx)

Update: Apparently it's on the menu for the end of January 2013. http://kforge.ros.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2012-December/004341.html

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stalin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/104/stalin/) on 2012-12-07**:
Thank you for your response. I was wondering if you could point me to specific materials about the Bullet engine, beside their website. According to Gazebo Developers, they're going to implement it by then end of January, and I would like to prepare myself a bit more in the meantime. Thanks much!

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-12-07**:
I don't have any more info on bullet other than their website/[wiki](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Main_Page). My info about the schedule was from the DRC kickoff meeting and the  the [roadmap](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Roadmap). Do you have more info?

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-12-10**:
Ah, I see: http://kforge.ros.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2012-December/004341.html

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/124/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-04**:
Someone know if the updates was finally success? about deformation . thnks